# Converting voice to text C#

Tags: c#, google-speech-api

I am trying to convert voice to text with the google API there is a test page https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/ where you can verify that your audio is converted to text, I am introducing my audio and for this page IF IT BECOMES A TEXT, but I am consuming the service from my program and I do not manage to do it, the following error is shown:
"Damaged file send audio again: Status (StatusCode = InvalidArgument, Detail = \" Invalid recognition \ 'config \': bad sample rate hertz. \ ")"

My code is as follows:

```
        string pathAudio = CreateAudio(Base64Audio);
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create();

        var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
        {                
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            LanguageCode = "es-MX",
        }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(pathAudio));

        foreach (var result in response.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                resultado = alternative.Transcript;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
```

They have some idea that it may be happening.

Comment: "bad sample rate hertz" is quite indicative of the problem. There is some issue with your microphone sample rate. Check your hardware configuration. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))

Comment: The situation is that the same audio I'm converting to text through the google page and there if it is converted but my program does not

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/basics) mentions:

> sampleRateHertz - (required) specifies the sample rate (in Hertz) of the supplied audio. (For more information on sample rates, see Sample Rates below.) The sampleRateHertz field is optional for FLAC and WAV files where the sample rate is included in the file header.

So the problem could be the missing `SampleRateHertz` configuration property, but if you are trying to send a WAV file (or FLAC), there might be a problem with `Base64Audio` or the `CreateAudio()` method - since the API is apparently unable to detect the sample rate.